# How can $B(a)$ be utilized in the attached question in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G := (V,E)$ be a graph. Show that there is a function $α : V → \{0,1\}$
such that, for each $v ∈ V$, at least half of the neighbours of $v$ have a different
$α$-value than $v$.
Here's the question. It is part of my Graph Theory homework and I've done every other problem except this one... I've tried an approach utilizing the fact that every graph $G$ contains a bipartite subgraph with at least half the edges, but that didn't work. Can somebody tell me how this hint is related to other theorems in Graph Theory? Because I'm really a little stuck around here.

Comment: Have you tried inducing on the size of the graph?

Comment: Hmmmmm That wouldn't help though because if we induce on that, we'd be stuck at the stage where we try to change the a value of some vertices and if we do, we'd need to change the a value of some other vertices and it goes on and on.

Comment: sure though I'll give it a try, see what it yields

Comment: @bitesizebo I don't think it works

Comment: Also forgot to put the definition of B(a) around here

Comment: For each α, define B(α) to be the number of edges
with different α-values on its ends. Then consider B(α)

Answer (score 1):

As you write in the comments, let $B(\alpha)$ denote the number of edges of $G$ that have different $\alpha$-values on the endpoints.

Hint: choose $\alpha$ so that $B(\alpha)$ is maximal and show that it has the desired property.

Solution:

> If there was a vertex $v$ such that less than half of its neighbours have $\alpha$-values different from $\alpha(v)$, then changing $\alpha(v)$ would increase $B(\alpha)$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I've been hinted (in the same hint) by a friend of mine just a few minutes ago and I figured the proof out. This is correct.